# Decrypted string is not encoded properly in subsequent Node sessions

Tags: node.js, character-encoding, base64, buffer, cryptojs

I have text of the form `crypto.randomBytes(30).toString("hex")` that I need encrypted.

Below is the encrypt and decrypt algorithms that I use.

```
import crypto from "crypto";

const ALGORITHM = "aes-256-ctr";
const IV_LENGTH = 16;
const ENCRYPTION_KEY = crypto.randomBytes(32);

export const encrypt = (text: string) => {
  const iv = crypto.randomBytes(IV_LENGTH);
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(ALGORITHM, ENCRYPTION_KEY, iv);
  const encryptedText = cipher.update(text, "utf8", "base64") + cipher.final("base64");

  return `${iv.toString("hex")}:${encryptedText}`;
};

export const decrypt = (text: string) => {
  const textParts = text.split(":");
  const iv = Buffer.from(textParts.shift(), "hex");
  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(ALGORITHM, ENCRYPTION_KEY, iv);
  const encryptedText = Buffer.from(textParts.join(":"), "base64");

  return decipher.update(encryptedText, "base64", "utf8") + decipher.final("utf8");
};
```

I run `node` in my terminal and am able to mess around with these functions in my `repl`-like environment.

When I am within that `node` session, I see the following:

```
const encryptedText = encrypt("0e1819ff39ce47ec80488896a16520bc6b8fcd7d55dc918c96c61ff8e426")
// Output: "9fa7486458345eae2b46687a81a9fcf5:LOrlVD06eotggmIPAq0z9yzP/EHoeQyZyK6IiBYKZMIWvWYLekmSe73OjlgXdWJVOrcTyWS/eP3UU2yv"

const decryptedText = decrypt(encryptedText);
// Output: "0e1819ff39ce47ec80488896a16520bc6b8fcd7d55dc918c96c61ff8e426"
```

Just like I want!

If I exit the `node` session, and open a new `node` session and copy and paste to decrypt the same string I get the following:

```
const decryptedText = decrypt(ENCRYPTED_TEXT_FROM_ABOVE)
// Output: "�Z<�\r����S78V��z|Z\u0013��\u001a}�����@ߩ����Ɣh���*����y\b�\u001d���l'�m�'�"
```

Why is this happening? What changed? Clearly it seems like the Node no longer knows how to display the characters or something. I don't know what encoding it is now.

I came across this because I store the encrypted data in Postgres and upon retrieving it, I sometimes need to decrypt it. For some reason, when I restart the node session it forgets how to read it.

The interesting thing is I can `decrypt(encrypt("another string")) => "another string"` in the new `node` terminal and it'll work, but the original string no longer does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decryption step is failing here since you are generating a new key for each session in the line:

```
const ENCRYPTION_KEY = crypto.randomBytes(32);
```

If you log the key like so:

```
console.log( { key: ENCRYPTION_KEY.toString("hex") });
```

You'll see the key is different for each run. So it makes sense that we fail to decrypt the encrypted data from a previous session!

If you change to using a fixed key:

```
const ENCRYPTION_KEY = Buffer.from("8b3d2068cf410479451eef41fe07d43e62ec80b962ae30cd99f7698499acfd61", "hex");
```

The output from each session should be decrypted in the next one.

Of course we won't want to leave keys in code, so it would be best to use an environment variable for this purpose.

Comment: It's so obvious in hindsight that it literally pains me.

Comment: Then... I suppose I shouldn't really care that I got this weird `�Z<�\r����S78V��z|Z\u0013��\u001a}�����@ߩ����Ɣh���*����y\b�\u001d���l'�m�'�` output, right? I fixed it and everything works, but I'm still puzzled that it would show that instead of a `utf8` string.

Comment: You could look at my code and in one minute see a bunch of issues I could miss for hours. It's always like that! Wood for the trees and all that. I think the reason we just see garbage is that the input is being mapped to a bunch of weird and wacky characters off in the nether regions of Unicode space.

Comment: True. Actually - since it's utf8 I suppose it's the expected result. Thanks!